# Worker role cloud service is not updating latest build code

Tags: c#, azure-worker-roles, azure-cloud-services

I am using **azure cloud service worker role** for processing queue when I am updating the package with latest changes on azure cloud service worker role and it uploads successfully but code changes not reflected for me. Even when I stopped that cloud service worker it still process the records from the azure queue.

Can Anyone help me to figure out what exactly happens.

Answer (score 1):

> I am updating the package with latest changes on azure cloud service worker role and it uploads successfully but code changes not reflected for me.

You could enable [remote debugging for your cloud service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vs-azure-tools-debug-cloud-services-virtual-machines#debug-a-cloud-service-in-azure) and make sure if it could execute your latest changes/code.

> Even when I stopped that cloud service worker it still process the records from the azure queue

Please check if local service configuration file has same settings with service configuration in the cloud, and please check if the cloud service are running on your local machine and it processes the queue. In addition, please make sure there are not another tasks or projects processing message from same queue.